# Is finish always scheduled before startActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity

```
startActivity(newActivity);
finish();
```

Assuming I'm calling it like above. Both calls are scheduled to happen on the UI thread after the end of the invoking method. However, is there a particular order in the scheduling? Is finish always scheduled before startActivity? or vice versa?

Comment: `Both calls are scheduled to happen on the UI thread after the end of the invoking method` Not quite true. Those actions would be executed some time later (there does not exist exactness here), but method/function does not matter. `Is finish always scheduled before startActivity?` how does possessing this information would influence your implementation code? If it does somehow, than you are doing something wrong. Or maybe you are asking just out of curiosity?

Comment: @azizbekian It doesn't matter to you what my motivation is. What is the answer to the question?

Comment: It **does** matter what your motivation is in order to provide an answer which you seek for. Your argument is invalid.

Comment: You should not be dependent on the ordering of those two method executions. Within your question you state, that you are somehow dependent on that. That's the reason why I tell that "you are doing something wrong".

Comment: @azizbekian The question asks if there is a particular ordering in the scheduling of both finish and startActivity, not whether I should depend on the ordering. Good to know I shouldn't depend on it, but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I didn't read a documentation about that but i think to start an activity, finish should executed after startActivity(activity)

Comment: @YusufÇağlar You can put finish() before or after startActivity(). My question isn't talking about the order of the calls but the order of the scheduling.

Comment: and i meant it :) If current activity destroys before starting a new activity, app would be in blank even if it lasts only just few milliseconds. I dont think that this is appropriate

Comment: You are assuming that the order of the calls is the same as the order of the scheduling. I'm pretty sure you can't just assume that.

Comment: @YusufÇağlar Hm...That might be correct. Your assumption, now that I think about it again.

Comment: @YusufÇağlar The correct answer has been posted. Your assumption is correct. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @RichyDavisWindow3 You're welcome

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When calling finish() on an activity, the method onDestroy() is executed this method can do things like:

1. Dimiss any dialogs(search dialogs) that activity was managing.
2. Close any cursors the activity was managing.
   And the activity is removed from the stack.

And calling startActivity(newActivity) creates and puts a new View on the Top.

Thus,if order is

```
startActivity(newActivity);

finish();
```

Then first newActivity is displayed and old one is detroyed.

But,if order is

```
finish();

startActivity(newActivity);
```

Then first the existing activity is destroyed and new one is created and displayed.

So, if we have lots of things to do in onDestroy()(like storing some datas) then calling startActivity() then finish() will be a good thing to do.Thus, the order depends on what we call first.

Comment: can you please elaborate??

Comment: Best to provide the code block which you are referring to as an example. Hard to help without the bigger picture.

Comment: @dazed'n'confused He's basically saying what I'm saying in my answer, which is the order of the scheduling is the same as the order of the calls. Plus more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

You should always **Start Before You Finish**

Hence the most desirable method call order would be,

```
startActivity(NewActivity);
finish();
```

Mark Murphy wrote an excellent [article](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/02/01/start-before-finish.html) about this.

Answer (score 1):

It will work in both the cases whether you write finish () before or after the start activity()

Answer (score 1):

So basically the order of the scheduling depends on the order of the calls. If you call finish() first, it will be added into the queue followed by startActivity(). Same goes for the other way around. Depending on how your implementation goes, if you require a specific order in the scheduling, simply call the functions in the order that you want the scheduling to occur.

Comment: currently waiting 2 days till I can accept this answer. In the meantime, this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It  should work is both cases.